# after migrating my project from angular v7 to v8, getting warnings related to @angular/fire

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

the warning that i am constantly getting, every time i run `yarn` or `npm install` is

```
warning " > @angular/fire@5.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "firebase@>= 5.5.7 <7".
```

my angular version is v8 and my @angular/fire version is ^5.2.1

I have already tried searching my problem on google, but nothing to be found on there. Also, i re-read @angular/fire documentation and all the supporting docs that they provide, even those for migration from v4 to v5 of @angular/fire, but nothing was helpful in this regard.

Comment: did you run this ? npm install firebase @angular/fire --save

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI yes i did that, and again tried after i saw your comment, the warning is still there.

Comment: ok now you need to run this npm install firebase@5.5.7

Comment: nope, i tried, the warning is still there.